# Python: duration of "with"

Tags: python, csv

I am using the csv.reader function to access a csv file using "with [x] as [y]"

The following code works:

```
countrow = 0
with open('mysheet.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    thesheet = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in thesheet:
        for mystring in row:
            shred = mystring.split(",")
        for x in range(0,8):
            matrix[countrow][x] = shred[x]
        countrow = countrow + 1
```

However, when I add a few lines after "thesheet", the last for loop does not appear to be called at all:

```
countrow = 0
with open('mysheet.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    thesheet = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

    thelength = sum(1 for row in thesheet) + 1
    dudes = 9
    matrix = [[0 for x in range(dudes)] for y in range(thelength)]

    for row in thesheet:
        for mystring in row:
            shred = mystring.split(",")
        for x in range(0,8):
            matrix[countrow][x] = shred[x]
        countrow = countrow + 1
```

(Note that the only reason the first version works is that I have my "matrix" variable stored in Spyder)

I can't see why adding these lines should make the existing code stop working. Am I missing something about how "with" works? Thanks!

Comment: `thelength = sum(1 for row in thesheet) + 1` has already consumed the iterator. You need to reset the pointer and create another reader object

Comment: What Padraic Cunningham is trying to say is that your use of `with` is fine, but your use of `csv.reader` isn't. You can only iterate once over a `csv.reader` (e.g. through generator comprehensions like `1 for row in thesheet`). If you want to read `csvfile` a second time (as you do in `for row in thesheet:`), you need to create a new `csv.reader`.

Comment: This fix works. Thanks!